# How configure Spatialite for PHP Version 5.6.14 (on Windows 7 and Apache 2.4)?

Tags: spatialite, php, apache

I'm on Windows 7, using PHP Version 5.6.14 on Apache 2.4 and I'm trying to access to a Spatialite database.

All works fine when execute "no spatial" SQL query in my PHP procedure but when I try to use the PtDistWithin in a query like ...

```
 SELECT .......... WHERE PtDistWithin(distr.geometry, MakePoint(13.571386, 37.314926, 4326), 1000);
```

the response is

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: MakePoint
```

I'm sure that my query is right because if I execute it on Spatialite GUI it works.

In my php.ini I've enabled as follow

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
[sqlite3]
sqlite3.extension_dir = D:\Programmi\Php\ext
```

and I've put in my PATH "D:\Programmi\Php\ext". In this directory there is

```
07/09/2015  16:32         8.118.531 mod_spatialite.dll
```

and all the others dll ... here you are the list

```
22/03/2015  16:43            62.671 libfreexl-1.dll
07/12/2014  23:35           113.152 libgcc_s_seh_64-1.dll
03/09/2015  18:09         1.335.271 libgeos-3-5-0.dll
03/09/2015  18:09           195.167 libgeos_c-1.dll
20/12/2014  10:01         1.546.608 libiconv-2.dll
20/04/2015  08:58           211.181 liblzma-5.dll
20/04/2015  09:36           461.564 libproj-9.dll
03/09/2015  18:13           956.115 libsqlite3-0.dll
07/12/2014  23:35         1.014.272 libstdc++_64-6.dll
15/02/2015  10:36         1.699.757 libxml2-2.dll
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the mod_spatialite must be loaded by executing SQL `SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite.dll')`. It requires also that `sqlite3_enable_load_extension` is called first.

Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756146/how-to-load-sqlite-extension-in-pdo and http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension.